# query result in TEZ and SPARK different (in spark correct)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive, apache-tez

query count(*) in hive(TEZ) and SPARK retuns diffrent result

example, hive(tez) (incorrect) returns 46 142 585, in spark (correct) returns 12 678 167

how get correct result in tez?

i use hdfs

set hive.auto.convert.join=false - does not work

set hive.compute.query.using.stats = false - does not work (returns strange result different from tez and spark -  47 685 940)

set hive.stats.autogather = false - does not work (returns strange result different from tez and spark -  47 685 940)

set hive.stats.autogather = true - does not work